# When extending a backbone model or view, how can i create properties that get created on the instance and not on the prototype?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to do:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.model.extend({
  someProp: { ... },
  .
  .
  });
```

but have 
`new MyModel().someProp === new MyModel().someProp` return `false`

as if i had done

```
function MyModel() {
 this.someProp = {...};
}
```

I dont want to put the assignment `this.someProp = {...};` in the `initialize` method because if i subclass MyModel, i ll have to repeat the assignment also in the subclass's initialize method again or remember to call the parents initialize from the children initialize every time i subclass, which it seems to me as a workaround rather than a solution. So, is there any other way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use it for multiple models, then one solution would be to create a standalone function that takes care of it, then you can call that function from the model's initialize method.

Here's an example

```
function addInstanceProperties() {
  this.someProp = 'hello';
  this.otherProp = 'world';
}

var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    //have to use 'call' so the context is set to this model
    addInstanceProperties.call(this); 
  }
});

var Child = Parent.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    addInstanceProperties.call(this);
  }
});
```

However, this isn't any different than having the property assignments in the parent and having the child call the parent's initialize method. And there is less code involved.

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.someProp = 'hello';
    this.otherProp = 'world';
  }
});

var Child = Parent.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    Parent.prototype.initialize.call(this);
  }
});
```

Unless you want to repeat the property assignments in each initialize method, this is really the only other way to do it in Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to avoid it in javascript

Comment: Also, if i dont need to add anything to child initialization, i could also omit the child initialize definition, is this correct?I mean,  If i dont override initialize in my childs, the parent's initialize will get called, correct?

Comment: You can get around that line of code in the children if you want. Instead of initialize, define "additionalInitialize: function() {...}" in the child. Then, in the parent, do "initialize: function() {...; this.additionalInitialize();}"

Answer (score 0):

I would actually recommend overriding the constructor in the parent class instead creating a separate function as Paul has suggested.

That way, if you do need a custom initialization function in child functions, the constructor retains the instance properties and you don't need to worry about managing scope or calling some global function, passing in `this` context, etc.

```
var Parent = Backbone.Model.extend({
  constructor: function(options){
    this.someProp = 'hello';
    this.otherProp = 'world';
    Backbone.Model.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments); 
  }
});

var child = Parent.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    // don't need to worry about setting up instance props anymore.
    // don't need to worry about invoking the overridden init method.
  }
});
```

This is the same idea as what Paul has done in his second block of code, except that the constructor is separated from initialize in backbone for this exact reason -- so that you can override / customize initialization actions without needing to copy/paste redundant construction options everytime do you do so.